# matlab efficient copying of matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, copying

I have matrix (a) with (1:10),<10 x 1> double. I would like to copy the values and rearrange them column wise into another matrix var. (b). See example below. Also, what method would be most efficient at this task?

```
matrix a    matrix b

1            1
2            2  2
3            3  3  3  
4            4  4  4  4
5            5  5  5  5  5
6            6  6  6  6  6  6
7            7  7  7  7  7  7  7
8            8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8
9            9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9
10           10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

update:
Hi once again Amro. How about if I wanted to define which values to copy. See below example:

```
matrix a    matrix b
column:      1  2  3  4  5  6  7

1            1
2            2  2
3               3  3  
4                  4  
5                     5  
6                     6     
7                        7  
8                        8     
9                           9  
10                         10 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
>> a = (1:10)'
a =
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
     8
     9
    10

>> b = tril(repmat(a,1,10))
b =
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     2     2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     3     3     3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     4     4     4     4     0     0     0     0     0     0
     5     5     5     5     5     0     0     0     0     0
     6     6     6     6     6     6     0     0     0     0
     7     7     7     7     7     7     7     0     0     0
     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     0     0
     9     9     9     9     9     9     9     9     9     0
    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10
```

Comment: @BernardUntalanJr.: I'm afraid your new specification is not complete. How do you define which values get copied?

Comment: I made an asinine error. Anyways, user1434725 provided a solution. Thanks for you solution to the first part of my question.

Comment: regarding the solution you provided, are there any other solutions that don't involve repmat?

Comment: @BernardUntalanJr.: what do you have against REPMAT? anyway here are a couple of alternatives: `tril(a(:,ones(1,10)))` or `tril(a*ones(1,10))`

Comment: repmat seems to run out of memory when dealing with large matrices

Answer (score 1):

I think in the second matrix you specified you made an error. I'm assuming you wanted to do something like this:

```
b =

 1     0     0     0     0     0
 2     2     0     0     0     0
 0     3     3     0     0     0
 0     0     4     4     0     0
 0     0     0     5     5     0
 0     0     0     0     6     6
```

this is simple to do:

```
%define vector of arbitrary length
a=1:6;
%generate b with shifted diagonal matrices
b=diag(a)+diag(a(2:end),-1);
```

the second argument of diag just shifts the resulting diagonal.